# SQL WHERE LIKE with tab

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

Seems like such a simple thing.  I need to specify a WHERE criteria with the LIKE operator and include a tab in the expression.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%Run1[TAB]%';
```

I've tried \t, \\t, %t and the char operator.

I am working in Sqlite.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
CAST(X'09' AS TEXT)
```

for the tab character

Comment: Thanks @hatchet, query:  SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%Run1' || X'09' || '%' does the trick!

Comment: glad that worked. I knew X'09' was the key, but wasn't sure whether it needed to be cast or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using DB2, but maybe this solution is something you can use on Sqlite also.

Try using the chr function. I think in ASCII the tab character has value 8. In DB2 the following works

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%' || chr(8) || '%'
```

Comment: My ascii has become a bit rustii

Comment: So such luck - "Query Error: no such function: chr Unable to execute statement", I do not think sqlite has a char like function